# Wordpress post title in functions

Tags: php, wordpress, function, http-headers

I'm attempting to set the post title as a HTTP header. I've tried a number of variations of the below code (with and without the `->ID` option) and nothing outputs or I get an `Trying to get property of non-object in` error:

```
is_admin() || add_action('send_headers', function(){
    global $post;
    $title = get_the_title($post->ID);
    header('X-IC-Title:' . $title);
}, 1);
```

Comment: What do you mean "nothing prints"? HTTP headers don't print to the browser. Do you mean that you're not seeing the added headers in your request?

Comment: please explain the question

Comment: @maiorano84 Apologies for my terminology. Yes, I mean that I'm not seeing the HTTP headers that I've requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is actually very close.

If you take a look at [this list](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) of all of your action hooks, you'll see that the `send_headers` action occurs before the Wordpress object is completely set up.

What this means is that the usual objects and functions that reference the Wordpress globals won't work at this point in the lifecycle. You actually have to hook into the core a little bit later so that you can retrieve Post-related data.

I'm not sure why you have the `is_admin() ||` check prefixing your action hook. `add_action` returns a call to `add_filter` ([Source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/plugin.php#L398)), which in turn returns a boolean value of `true` ([Source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/plugin.php#L106)).

Short-circuiting wouldn't be of any use to you here, so I've modified your code to the following:

```
add_action('wp', function(){
    global $post;
    $title = get_the_title($post->ID);
    header('X-IC-Title:' . $title);
}, 1);
```

I've tested this in a clean Bedrock installation on a Homestead server and I'm seeing the new header in my network output(screenshot attached).

[image: Bedrock Test]

Hopefully this helps!