# Using Custom Post Type Title inside functions.php while creating a custom WPForms Smart Tags function

Tags: php, wordpress, smart-tags

I have created a Custom Post Type in Wordpress called Listings.

I am including the WPforms Lite form on each Listings page. I would like to  get and use the custom post type's title inside my functions.php while implementing a WPForms custom Smart Tag.

Using the documentation provided by WPForms here: [WPforms Custom Smart Tags](https://developers.wpforms.com/docs/create-a-custom-smart-tag/) I can get the static link to work, I am able to select the `{download_link}` (in my case `{listing_title}`) tag from the example in the subject of the form and have the link display as the subject in the email that is sent out.

I would like to replace the link (string) with a dynamic title that is fetched based on which Listings post the form is being submitted on.

I have tried using `wp_title();` and `get_the_title()`, but neither are working. I am not exactly sure why I cannot get the title this way. I am guessing that the Wordpress loop has something to do with it or that a custom post type requires something additional/different.

I have read and tried a couple posts, listed below, but with no success.

- [Wordpress post title in functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40099625/wordpress-post-title-in-functions)
- [Get the title of custom post type in another loop](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/239386/get-the-title-of-custom-post-type-in-another-loop)

Lastly, I must mention that WPforms has Smart Tags that reference Page and Post titles but they do not work either. This I am guessing is again due to the fact that I am trying it with a Custom Post Type (Listings).

My code:

```php
/**
 * Register the Smart Tag so it will be available to select in the form builder.
 *
 * @param array $tags
 * @return array
 */
function wpf_dev_register_smarttag( $tags ) {

    // Key is the tag, item is the tag name.
    $tags['listing_title'] = 'Listing Title';

    return $tags;
}

add_filter( 'wpforms_smart_tags', 'wpf_dev_register_smarttag' );

/**
 * Process the Smart Tag.
 *
 * @param string $content
 * @param string $tag
 * @return string
 */
function wpf_dev_process_smarttag( $content, $tag ) {

    // Only run if it is our desired tag.
    if ( 'listing_title' === $tag ) {
        // $link = echo get_the_title();
        // Replace the tag with listing title.
        $content = ; // SOMETHING RELATED TO LISTING TITLE
    }

    return $content;
}

add_filter( 'wpforms_smart_tag_process', 'wpf_dev_process_smarttag', 10, 2 );
```

I will need to set the `$content` variable to the current listing post's title

Seen here:

```php
$content = ; // SOMETHING RELATED TO LISTING TITLE
```