# Elementor custom query filter by post category

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I am creating a custom archive page with Elementor Theme Builder which will be applied to all category pages. The traditional 'Archive' widget shows all the posts and the post widget requires a term.

How can I get the posts to display dynamically on the respective archive page using Elementor Custom Query Filter? https://developers.elementor.com/custom-query-filter/

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/my_custom_filter', function( $query ) {
    // Get current meta Query
    $meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );

    // If there is no meta query when this filter runs, it should be initialized as an empty array.
    if ( ! $meta_query ) {
        $meta_query = [];
    }

    // Append our meta query
    $meta_query[] = [
        'key' => 'category',
        'value' => get_the_ID(),
        'compare' => '=',
    ];
    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
} );
```

Comment: Related content: [Wordpress post title in functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40099625/2943403)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the archive posts widget instead, with the query set to current query, so it automatically detects the archive category.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this for other users coming here from the top search of google:

You can totally do this, but you need to pass the post parameters from the query function:

```
function custom_query_callback( $query ) {
  // grab curent post data
  global $post;
  $id = $post->ID;
  // grab curent post category data
  $cat_id = get_the_category($id);
  $cat = $cat_id[0]->cat_ID;;
  // add category filter to elm query
  $query->set( 'cat', $cat);
}
add_action( 'elementor/query/custom_related_posts', 'custom_query_callback' );
```

additionally you can add this to link a button to the archive page:

```
function category_link_shortcode(){
  // grab current post data
  global $post;
  $id = $post->ID;
  // grab current post category data
  $cat_id = get_the_category($id);
  $cat = $cat_id[0]->cat_ID;;
  // grab current post category link
  $link = get_category_link($cat);
  // return for elementor button link dynamic tag
  return $link;
}
add_shortcode('category_link_shortcode', 'category_link_shortcode');
```

you can use these on loop grid query as well as standard posts widget query